# Перенос при помощи flex-wrap

Tags: css3, html5, flexbox, responsive, response

Проблема состоит в следующем. Подогнали мн "хорошо написанный" сайт.Есть на сайте вывод инфы через flex. В одной строке flex - вложенные ещё две,а в них по 2 блока, итого в одной строке 4 блока (это сделано было, как я понял, чтобы при уменьшении размера экрана, блоки по два выводились). Также там имеется кнопка Больше\Меньше, которая через скрипт в неактивном состоянии выводит 5 строк (половину), в активном все. Вопрос состоит в том что при адаптации часть блоков торчит из-за края родительского элемента, как можно организовать правильную адаптацию. Исходники, по понятным причинам пока не могу скинуть, а вот скрины и ссылку - могу.
Скрин самой проблемы:
[image: Скрин адаптивки]

Ссылка на это убожество. 
[Мой рабочий хостинг](http://ds03.kl.com.ua/)
Так как мне это править - подскажите как можно это решить? Там по ходу весь сайт запилен на флексе, переверстывать всё ой как не хочется.

Comment: или в какую сторону хоть копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас в стилях стоит

```
section.education-speciality {

    max-height: 1726px;
```

max-height на мой взгляд в даyном случае лучше рассчитывать с помощью функции calc, например для 5 рядов

```
max-height: calc(var(--box) * 5)
```

если конечно задан размер блока --box

Comment: Подскажите, как мне тогда вывести переменную var? Допустим я ее в js определил, дальше подставлять в скрипт? Или в css прописать, судя по вашему ответу?

Comment: в ccs пишешь
:root {